# Cold observable in RxJava

Tags: rx-java, observable, subscriber

In reactive programming, cold observable starts emitting values only when observers have subscribed to it.

I have a question in this context.

Suppose I subscribe S1 on observable O at time T1, and hence S1 starts receiving values.Then I subscribe S2 on O at time T2.

Would S2 receive values emitted by O between T1 and T2?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that S2 would receive values only from time T2.

There are several operators you can use that will replay emitted values. You can use a combination of `replay()`, `publish()`, `refCount()`, etc, to allow replaying values between T1 and T2. Here is a [good overview of cold versus hot observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339).